# Taxonomy not working with the ECK module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have created a image gallery using the [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck)  module and for some reason the taxonomy is not working.

These are the step I follow to created the image gallery.

1. Created a Entity called Media
2. Created a Bundle called Pictures
3. Add a Image Field (image field is from Flickr Field so all the images are been pull from Flickr)
4. Add a term reference field (taxonomy)
5. I created a views to display the images (http://test-darrylnorris.gotpantheon.com/media/pictures-gallery)
6. Finally add some images to the entity media --> bundle pictures and some taxonomy.

But when I click on the taxonomy term is showing me this error

> There is currently no content classified with this term.

That's not true they are different taxonomy using the term. Also I'm using the [Content Taxonomy](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy)  to provide the Auto-complete field.

How can I troubleshoot this problem ? Or why my taxonomy terms are not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answer my question on Drupal.org forums.

> Taxonomy only works with nodes. It's been hard-coded that way.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2339147#comment-9151769